# How do I use the JS fetch api system to replace jQuery AJAX system for multiple form fields triggered by onBlur?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, fetch-api

I have around 160 form fields (on a tabbed form) similar to this:

```
<form id="7" name="7" action="#" method="post">
<input type="text" id="houseName" name="houseName" value="<?=$existingValue[0]['houseName']?>
<input type="text" id="streetName" name="streetName" value="<?=$existingValue[0]['streetName']?>
...
</form>
```

I am trying to make it so that when a user enters or removes data from the text field, then takes the focus of the field, the new field value is sent by fetch API to the PHP on the server to be checked and if passes, inserted into the database. The server PHP will send a return to confirm or alert the user to the data being accepted or rejected for failing checks.

Once the return comes back, I'm hoping to get it to add a class to the relevant `input` field and add a html `span` with one of two specific classes, depending on success or failure of the data being processed.

I'm having great trouble understanding how the fetch API system works and have failed at getting anything to succeed. I've spent many hours reading but cannot find any straight forward explanations or examples of how to structure a fetch API call to work for my end result. Many online documents seem to be slightly conflicting on how I can ultilise a PHP target. For example:

```
fetch("//127.0.0.1/collect/post.2.php")
```

or

```
fetch("./collect/post.2.php")
```

Does the full URL have to be called from the JS code or can it be done by local path relative to the server (as it has been previously on the older jQuery/AJAX version I'm trying to replace)?

Can the fetch code reside in a separate file like app.2.js and be called in the head of the html document, or must it be inline?

Does the PHP code in post.2.php require specific formatting to work with fetch?

Can this be done with one piece of fetch API code for all input fields or will it require an individual block of code for each input field?

Please be patient with me - I'm not young and learning this stuff is not easy when there are no plain English examples. They all seem to assume everyone is at an experienced level to start with! I am not looking for someone to write me the code - I want to learn, but a code example with some straightforward explanation would be really appreciated.

EDIT

As per request by ADyson, this is the previous code for doing the ajax actions:

```
function blurHandler() {
    var id = this.id;
    $.post('./collect/post.2.php?data=' + secData, $('#'+id).serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#errorText_"+id).html(data['errorText_'+id]);
        $("#resultImg_"+id).html(data['resultImg_'+id]);
    }, 'json' );
}
```

I believe this relies on the following line which is in the html header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And here is a sample of the PHP that is initiated on the server end. The `xID` value used in the database handling is extrapolated from the `'data='` string.

```
    if(isset($_POST['houseName'])) {
    $userInput = $_POST['houseName'];
    if(trim($userInput) == "") { $userInput = NULL; }
    try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $database.table01 SET `houseName` = :userinput WHERE `xID` = :xid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':userinput', $userInput, PDO::PARAM_STR, 32);
        $stmt->bindParam(':xid', $xID, PDO::PARAM_INT, 11);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) { catchMySQLerror($e->getMessage()); }
    $report_name = array();
    if($userInput == NULL) {
        $report_name['errorText_houseName'] = "This field cannot be left blank";
        $report_name['resultImg_houseName'] = "<img src=\"./img/form_boo.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10008;\" title=\"&#10008;\">";
    } else {
        $report_name['errorText_houseName'] = NULL;
        $report_name['resultImg_houseName'] = "<img src=\"./img/form_yay.gif\" class=\"resultImg\" alt=\"&#10004;\" title=\"&#10004;\">";
    }
    echo json_encode($report_name);
}
```

This is all fairly old though functional. I do not know how to transpose this functionality into using the fetch API.

Comment: The browser constructs the final URL based on what you enter. How this is done is no different, no matter what client you use to make the AJAX request. Likewise, where you place the fetch() code is no different than any other AJAX client. And nothing need change in the PHP, providing you make the finished request the same - all PHP sees is the data in the HTTP request, it has no knowledge of how that request was generated.

Comment: If you've used jQuery's $.ajax function before, then the key concepts are all identical. It's just using a different client to do the same thing (a bit like switching between Thunderbird and Windows Mail for reading emails, for example). If you've got some $.ajax code which worked correctly, and you're trying to convert it to fetch, then please show us the working code, and your best attempt to so far at using fetch to write something equivalent, then maybe we can help you get it right. But none of the concerns you've raised above are a problem by themselves.

Comment: Or if it's a new piece of work, please show us an example of what you're doing - add some PHP so we can what the target is, then show the fetch code, and include any relevant data and/or HTML which it relies on. Then finally, tell us what error messages and/or unexpected behaviour you see (either in the browser window, or in your browser's Developer Tools - console and network tools especially) when you try to run the code. Again in that scenario, once we have a reproducible example, we can help you with it.

Comment: What we won't do though, is produce you a generic fetch tutorial, because this isn't a tutorial site. We answer specific questions about specific problems. There are 1000s of tutorials out there as it is. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data is not a bad one, I think it goes through each step in a good amount of detail. Obviously, as most of them do, they assume you have a basic knowledge of HTTP and of what AJAX is (otherwise you're really never going to understand anything else which is based on those concepts).

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the comments, they are appreciated. That did explain why I had seen differences in the fetch url styles (some being full addresses while others looking like local paths!) I understand this is not a tutorial place, and I have already read the one you linked to, last night! I did not find it helped me much as I could not understand how to set my fetch situation up for my end result. I did not have a json file to refer to. Sadly that tutorial left me just as confused as when I started.

Comment: Hm well that bit is mainly about receiving data rather than sending it. And JSON is only one type of data you can send and receive - in fact you can send/receive anything you like within a HTTP request, from plain text to large binary files and data streams. The [second section](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data#toc-handling-more-requests-like-post) of the tutorial is closer to your scenario (now you've shown it to us), as it talks about sending data. But it still talks about sending in JSON format, rather than form-data format.

Comment: And it seems like maybe the data format is what you're struggling with mainly, although you haven't really articulated it. Actually I think Mehmet's answer below should help you deal with that. It's the lack of an equivalent function to jQuery's .serialize() which might have thrown you, I suspect. Having said all that, your PHP function does return JSON, so actually the first bit of the tutorial, about receiving JSON in the response is still relevant as well - fetch doesn't know (or care) whether the JSON it gets back from the server was generated from a static file or from a PHP script.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks! I am attempting to use Mehmets answer below, however it's not doing anything at all at the moment. No transaction across the network, no errors, nothing in console at all. It's a little bit disappointing to not even have an error to work with but I am feeling a bit more confident that the entire matter is not as much of a problem collection as I had initially thought!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) for this.

The URL resolving algorithm of [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) is exactly the same with AJAX.

Fetch API uses [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which are introduced to JavaScript with [ECMAscript 2015 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). XMLHttpRequest uses callbacks; that is why they look so different.

You don't need to modify the backend code after switching to Fetch API.

Please update the form inputs as below:

```html
<form id="7" name="7" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="houseName" name="houseName" onblur="blurHandler(this)" value="<?=$existingValue[0]['houseName']?>
  <input type="text" id="streetName" name="streetName" onblur="blurHandler(this)" value="<?=$existingValue[0]['streetName']?>
...
</form>
```

The code below submits the blurred input and its value as the single member of a virtual form.

```js
function blurHandler(input) {
  const id = input.id;

  // Create a new FormData instance
  const formData = new FormData();

  // Append the input into FormData
  formData.append(input.name, input.value);

  // Now we perform the POST
  fetch(`./collect/post.2.php?data=${secData}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData, // Fetch API can deal with FormData instances automatically
  })
  .then((response) => response.json()) // Parse server response as JSON
  .then((data) => { // Parsed JSON passed as `data`
    document.getElementById(`errorText_${id}`).innerHTML = data[`errorText_${id}`];
    document.getElementById(`resultImg_${id}`).innerHTML = data[`resultImg_${id}`];
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Trace the error and pop an alert if anything goes wrong
    console.trace(error);
    alert('Failed to submit form');
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Mehmet, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure why but I cannot get your solution to work. I would imagine that because we are putting all of what you have coded into the `function blurHandler()` block, it would work once focus was taken off any of the input fields. However it does not do this. It doesn't do anything - no errors in the console, just nothing. I see in some places you are using different types of single quotes. Maybe this is causing it to not work?

Comment: Could you add  `console.log(formData);` line under `const formData` line? And a `console.log(data);` line under `then((data) => {`? Strings enclosed with backticks are called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and I don't think that they are the problem. Otherwise they would cause a syntax error.

Comment: Thinking about it, I believe the code you proposed for the answer will submit the entire form as a whole, and not each field individually as focus is taken off them? I do not think that is best - it would seem rather heavy handed to submit 160 fields each time just one is updated, but I want to save each one as it's updated. Hence the idea and original model of it saving just the one field that focus is lost from. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi again Mehmet. I understand your comment about having a syntax error. You're right, there isn't one at all so I guess that answers that problem. I have added the recommended lines you have suggested but still nothing is triggering. It simply is not firing as a response to any input losing focus. Perhaps the actual `function blurHandler()` requires jQuery to work?

Comment: Hi Dan, I updated my answer: now `blurHandler` is assigned as blur handler to all form elements. If you need a vanilla solution then please tell me which types of inputs (input, select, textarea etc.) you use in your forms.

Comment: Hi Mehmet. I changed what I am using to your updated answer, and now I am getting an error in the console! It is more than I was getting before so I think this is progress! I am getting _Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined_ at the end of the line `$(':input').blur(blurHandler);`

Also, yes this form does use pretty much every sort of form field there is in later stages. It uses inputs of type text, email and password. It uses select, checkbox and textarea. Does that help? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Dan, it seems you are not using jQuery anymore. I updated my answer and now `blurHandler` is added with vanilla code.

Comment: Hi Mehmet. My apologies if I had not made that clear at the beginning - I'm trying to use the fetch api system because I want to stop using jQuery on this project. I actual php at the back end will also be changed in favour of a better mysql structure but I can worry about that later once I get this part working and start seeing the correct messages going back and forward. Sadly your last update once again gives no errors but no action at all, same as 2 updates ago. I feel worried since we should be getting closer to a success with the recognised removal of jQuery.

Comment: Where do you put this piece of code in the HTML document? Try putting it just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: On second thought, I think the fastest way is to add the onblur listeners inline. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Mehmet. I did have the script in a .js file that was loaded in the head right by the css file. I have shifted it to the bottom of the html page now and tried your most recent update - which works for inputs! But not for selects or textareas. Also still unsure how you can make the responses change/add a class to the input but I will try to noodle that one out also. Thanks for your help to date!

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to add the `onblur="blurHandler(this)"` to the select and textarea fields. My error there. They do work. I am just trying to figure out how to get it to add a class to the initial `input` now, as per initial question.

Comment: I think I have it all sorted out now, thank you Mehmet for your help! Much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help Dan :)

Comment: It still does not work at all for checkboxes though, so still not really the right answer.